# View item duplicates based on total views

Tags: views

I have a view that simply loads all the latest articles but I ran into some strange problem. Each time I visit an article, the `view count` increases but this also means that a certain article will appear in the as much as the count shows.

For example:

```
View:
- Article 1
- Article 2
```

When I click on Article 1 my `view` updates to:

```
View:
- Article 1
- Article 1
- Article 2
```

I hope this is clear enough to understand.

Note: maybe worth mention I'm setting up a `service` so in my `json api` I get the same results

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by removing `Node count: node id` I used the wrong `field`to display the `id`